# Как можно сделать данный код чище?

Tags: java

Метод принимает параметр в виде номера метода и в зависимости от него вызывает нужную функцию вычисления хеш кода.

```
  if(methodNum == 0) {
    hashCode = getHashDivine(randomArr[j]);
  } else if(methodNum == 1) {
    hashCode = getHashSquare(randomArr[j]);
  } else if(methodNum == 2) {
    hashCode = getHashCollapse(randomArr[j]);
  } else if(methodNum == 3) {
    hashCode = getHashMultiply(randomArr[j]);
  } else {
    hashCode = getHashUniversal(randomArr[j]);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
interface HashOperation {
  int getHash(int value);
}

@NotNull
HashOperation getHashOperation(int method) {
  switch(method) {
    case 0:
      return value -> getHashDivine(value);
    ...
    default:
      return value -> getHashUniversal(value);
  }
}

int hashCode = getHashOperation(methodNum).getHash(randomArr[j]);
```

Comment: И в самом деле в Java это считают более простым (чистым, т.е. легким для понимания и поддержки)? С т.з. поддержки (изменения количества видов функций хэширования) создание единственной функции с аргументами method и value будет ничем не хуже (но безусловно, понятней, т.к. меньше сущностей), чем возврат интерфейса